# 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant error

Tags: actionscript-3

I am very, very new to AS3 and trying to edit some of my templates. I get this message... 
Can someone please help me what to do step by step? Like I said, I am very new and need step by step.

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 10  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 23  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 28  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 33  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 38  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MouseEvent.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the classes youre referring to in the code are not imported.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import those classes before you can use them (see [Curtis Morley's post](http://curtismorley.com/2007/06/20/flash-cs3-flex-2-as3-error-1046/) for me details)

Add the following to the top of your document:

```
import flash.events.*
```